# Show/Hide Popup's and chat box depending on radio button check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, radio-button

I have one requirement that need to be done in js/jquery.
I have one contact button, which on click will display floating contact box (like normal live chats). 
Also i have one live chat in which chat is embedded via adding a js widget code [  code]. What i need is, upon clicking the contact button, 2 radio buttons(one with just a form popup and another one is live chat). on clicking the live chat radio button, the live chat should start display in the website(like normal chat position: please see the link eg: https://chat.zendesk.com/) .

Also at the same time the floating contact box should hide and instead the chat box should display.

So guys please help me to show a demo of this, since i am new to js/jquery work.
It would be very greatful, if you guys help me to show a demo of this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted any of it?

Comment: Hello Jared: sorry i didnt get you.... can u please explain a little bit? I need a sample demo of this. it would be helpful if you can just show a sample demo of this... thanks

Comment: Please provide with what you have tried so far for us to help you out. I would suggest getting yourself familiar with what Stack Overflow is.

Comment: Hello Sid Joshi, I will provide. Can you please describe one thing? How to show/hide widget section(eg: chat box) which is embedded in js script tag...

Comment: I provided an example of showing/hiding, just for clarification though this is for help/debugging etc. code, not writing from scratch so next time please provide something you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show whatever is directly after it once it is clicked, edit #more to whatever you are trying to show.

```
<input type="radio">Select To Show
<p id="more">More</p>

#more {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + #more {
  display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JaredBledsoe/ku4vjcw5/

Comment: Hello i will send you the code in which i need to edit. can you please cooperate with me to solve the issue?

Comment: Sure, post it to codepen/jsfiddle and I can give it a shot.

Comment: This is the code link: https://pastebin.com/eUx775jq
Please check the following portion.  $("#customer-chat-iframe").hide();   
What i need is i have one live chat, and it is embedded in an iframe. Initially i need to hide the chat. Upon clicking the radiobutton, chat needs to be shown.  " #customer-chat-iframe " is the iframe id.

Comment: This is the external website(chat link not orginal) iframe <iframe id="customer-chat-iframe" name="mcs_828490610417_" src="https://livechat.testwebsite.com/php/app.php?widget-iframe-content" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: medium none; outline: medium none; position: fixed; display: block; z-index: 999999; bottom: -355px; right: 30px; overflow: hidden; min-width: 279px; min-height: 368px; width: 340px; height: 400px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">

Comment: Ok, so could you clarify again what you're wanting? From what I'm getting, you want a user to click "Contact Us" and have two buttons pop up?